# How to destroy / Delete Active accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion, destroy

How can we destroy active accordion with all the content is have in it.

I started with this function

```
function DesctroyThisAccordion() {
var active = jQuery("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active');
 jQuery("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active').remove('h3');
jQuery("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active').remove('div');
}
```

I am using jQuery UI plugin for accordion

I am trying to find the active accordion and delete its h3 and div content.

i works if i select the last in  accordion

```
//jQuery("h3[class^='Title']:last").remove('h3');
//jQuery("div[class^='ui-accordion-content']:last").remove('div');
```

But i want it for active accordion

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i didn't find any help on this question.
I found solution, which may be helpful for any who are in same need.

```
jQuery("h3[class^='Title'][aria-selected='true']").remove('h3');
jQuery("div[class^='ui-accordion-content'][style^='display: block;']").remove('div');
```

Answer (score 10):

I used:

```
$("#myAccordion").accordion("destroy");    // Removes the accordion bits
$("#myAccordion").empty();                // Clears the contents
```

If you only empty the accordion container, it still retains accordion properties and will not be reusable as an accordion. Here's the [destroy documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$("#accordion h3").remove();
$("#accordion-cost div").remove();
```

Removes all h3 and div elements inside accordion.